# TextView showing on design preview, but not in actual Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

I have an XML layout in a second Activity that shows one of two `LinearLayouts` based on if a user is logged in or not, and the `TextView` I have never shows the text in the app, but it does render it correctly when I look at the "Design" panel in the layout editor

The `TextView` is there (if I set a background color, it shows that color) but the Text itself never renders.

Clicking a button on `MainActivity` results in starting the `LoginActivity`, which has the `onCreate` (it's Kotlin):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout)
```

And layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/loggedOut"
        android:padding="24dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hint="Username"
                android:inputType="textCapCharacters" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/passPin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:hint="PIN"
                android:inputType="numberPassword" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/passSubmit"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/loggedIn"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:padding="24dp">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loggedInMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="You're currently logged in"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/passLogout"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logout" />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is what Android Studio shows (those errors are `TextInputLayout` bugs where it says it can't find the hide password icon and such)
[image: What Android Studio shows me]

And this is what my device shows
[image: What I get on my device]

**Edit:** I've removed everything in the layout file except for the `TextView` and a parent `LinearLayout` and it's still not showing.

Comment: I tried removing the `TextInputLayout` to see if that was the issue. While the design warnings went away, the issue still persists

Comment: What if you remove this line `android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Headline" />`?

Comment: Nope, just tried that, and actually even reduced XML to just `LinearLayout` and `TextView`

Comment: have you tried changing the color of the textview? and hardcoding it's size? Also set a background color on the textview, to see where it is.

Comment: @rosualin Just tried, no effect

Comment: change the linear layour in a relative layour, and set the textview as alignparenttop, alignparentleft, and see if it is visible then? also remove the android:textAppearance and text:alignment, see what happens then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. Switching `android:text="You're currently logged in"` to `android:text="You\'re currently logged in"` fixed it. So I guess Android requires escaping single quotes when setting the text in XML?

Found by using the layout inspector tool, which showed `mText` as having no value

Comment: Yes, it does. But Lint should have complained for it.

Comment: Hmm, didn't see that error ever, only issue it gave was complaining that I hardcoded the string. I'm on Android Studio 3 Canary 4, so maybe it's just buggy?

Comment: Or maybe Lint is misconfigured - You can mute its complaints at your will.